# Sending Web Requests without Response

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I have some problems in this console program. I want send many requests to a website with this loop without response, because the response adds more delay, and I don't need the response.

So after I run this program it just sends two requests and then it's stops and does nothing. Please help me to solve this problem.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string post2;
            for (int i = 111; i < 222; i++)
            {
                post2 = i.ToString();
                System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://google.com");
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.KeepAlive = true;
                request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
                request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
                string postData = post2;
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);         
                Console.WriteLine(post2);
            }                              
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? what is the output?

Comment: no it's send first & second request then stop.

Comment: when I hold mouse pointer on this code 
`Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();`
show me this help:
`Stream HttpWebRequest .GetRequestStream () (+1 overload(s))`
I think if change overload from one to another number may this problem solve,but I don't know how write this without error.

Answer (score 0):

.NET limits to two connections by default. You can increase the limit if needed, but the real issue is that you are not closing your streams.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string post2;
            for (int i = 111; i < 222; i++)
            {
                post2 = i.ToString();
                System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://google.com");
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.KeepAlive = true;
                request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
                request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
                string postData = post2;
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                // You need to close the request stream when you're done writing to it.
                using(Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);         
                    Console.WriteLine(post2);
                }
                // Even if you don't need the response, you still need to close it.
                request.GetResponse().Close();
            }                              
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You say:".NET limits to two connections by default. You can increase the limit" exactly I need this.Please write those code to change default connections tanks.